# Weka Creating Instance Object error

Tags: java, weka

I was looking a programmatic exampple of Weka from http://weka.wikispaces.com/Programmatic+Use . However, I think because of the version of my Weka jar (3.7.7), it gives error on this line:

```
 Instance iExample = new Instance(4);

 Error: Cannot instantiate the type Instance
```

What kind of change should I do on the code?

Comment: You might get this error when trying to instantiate an abstract class. Maybe `Instance` is abstract in the version of Weka you are using.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, according to this [documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Instance.html) `Instance` is an interface. Which is why your getting this error. You will need create one of the implementing classes eg,

```
Instance iExample = new DenseInstance(4);
```

Perhaps that example is out of date.

Comment: absoulty you are right, the code is belonged to older version of weka. Anyway thank you for your help